# Google doc switch styles with hot keys

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there was a way to set hot keys to easily switch between styles in a Google doc.  Say, for example, I want to switch between a 1 inch and 2 inch right indent, but I don't want to have to use the ruler every time to do that, and instead just use a key combo to switch.  Is there a way I can do that?  If it requires writing a script, I can do that if I'm pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are keyboard shortcuts in Windows at least (in Chrome using Google Docs)

[image]